# Rails 6 Integration test exception is too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just set up a brand new rails 6.1 application on Ruby 3.0.

Everything is working as expected, except for the IntegrationTest.

Whenever there's a error in the test, the stack trace is gigantic and unreadable. I'm not sure if it's a wrong config or a bug. It's so long it doesn't fit VSCode terminal. I had to pop up a system terminal to be able to go to the first line of the stack trace and understand what's going on

Here's an snippet of the stack trace:

```
rails test test/controllers/api/v1/sessions_controller_test.rb:23

E

Error:
API::V1::SessionsControllerTest#test_it_generates_token_on_successfull_auth:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `password' for #<API::V1::SessionsControllerTest:0x000000012d5d6ca8 @_routes=nil, @NAME="test_it_generates_token_on_successfull_auth", @failures=[#<Minitest::UnexpectedError: Unexpected exception>], @assertions=0, @integration_session=#<#<Class:0x0000000107222768>:0x00000001072221a0 @_routes=nil, @app=#<OcaServer::Application:0x000000011db277d0 @_all_autoload_paths=["/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/channels", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/controllers", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/controllers/concerns", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/helpers", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/jobs", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/mailers", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/models", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/models/concerns", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/services"], @_all_load_paths=["/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/lib", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/vendor", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/channels", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/controllers", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/controllers/concerns", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/helpers", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/jobs", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/mailers", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/models", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/models/concerns", "/Users/joao/code/one_cent_auction/oca_server/app/services"], @app=#<ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization:0x000000010f88e5b8 @app=#<Rack::Sendfile:0x000000010f88e770 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Static:0x000000012d407350 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Executor:0x000000012d407490 @app=#<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x000000011dc782d8 @name="ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache", @local_cache_key=:active_support_cache_null_store_local_cache_4540, @app=#<Rack::Runtime:0x000000012d4076c0 @app=#<Rack::MethodOverride:0x000000012d407800 @app=#<ActionDispatch::RequestId:0x000000012d407a30 @app=#<ActionDispatch::RemoteIp:0x000000012d407b98 @app=#<Rails::Rack::Logger:0x000000012d407cd8 @app=#<ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions:0x000000012d407dc8 @app=#<ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions:0x000000012d407ee0 @app=#<ActionDispatch::
```

It goes on for thousands of lines.

Here's my `test_helper`

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"
require 'webmock/minitest'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

On another project that I am working on there was never an stacktrace that was that big.

-- Edit
Just to clarify what's triggering the error:

```
require 'test_helper'

class API::V1::SessionsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  
  setup do
    @password = Faker::Internet.password
    @user = create(:user)
    @user.update! password: password, password_confirmation: password
  end

  #...
end
```

The error is happening because I called a variable that hasnt been declared. `password` instead of `@password`

The problem is that I was expecting the stack trace to be as simple as:

```
API::V1::SessionsControllerTest#test_it_generates_token_on_successfull_auth:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `password' for #<API::V1::SessionsControllerTest:0x000000012d5d6ca8>
```

And not show the entire content of the SessionsControllerTest class.

Is that a normal Rails 6.1 behavior on Ruby 3? I don't recall it happening on Ruby 2.

Here's what I was expecting, reproducing the same error on a Ruby 2, Rails 6.1 application:

```
rails test test/controllers/jobs_controller_test.rb:15

E

Error:
JobsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `it_will_fail' for #<JobsControllerTest:0x0000000115b7c620>
    test/controllers/jobs_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:JobsControllerTest>'
    test/test_helper.rb:24:in `run'
```

Comment: what's on that test? it's saying you are calling `password` somewhere but it's undefined

Comment: I added some clarifications @arieljuod. The problem is not that I don't know what the error is. But the stacktrace is unusually long.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution for this?